# Where can I find ISTQB Foundation mock exams with reliable answers?

Tags: manual-testing, istqb, mock

> Where can I find ISTQB mock exams with reliable answers?

I have heard that there are a lot of sites with mock exams but they told me to be careful because some of their answers are not correct.

Comment: For free or will you pay for a book ?

Comment: It depends what you mean by reliable ;-) Reliable to pass exam or reliable to implement in practice.

Answer (score 4):

Don't know how reliable they are, but some of my colleagues recommend [this site](http://istqbquestionbank.blogspot.se/2012/01/istqb-foundation-sample-question-paper.html) which they used before the exam (and they did all pass).

I haven't tried it myself though.

Comment: Wish I could upvote you twice for posting such a great link!! Thanks!

Comment: "Sorry, the page you were looking for in this blog does not exist."

Comment: Some of the questions there are not relevant to Foundation Level and some of the answers are bit vague. So, please be careful when you use that site

Answer (score 4):

- I've read ["Foundations of Software Testing: ISTQB Certification"](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=_fZnXwAACAAJ) by Dorothy Graham et al. For each chapter of [Syllabus](http://www.istqb.org/downloads/viewcategory/16.html) it has sample example questions, together with correct answers and reference to the paragraph explaining why it is correct.
- On [ISTQB site](http://www.istqb.org/downloads/viewcategory/41.html) there is is also a *free* sample of exam questions and correct answers but without explanation why it is correct.

There are tons of Web sites with obviously incorrect answers. What I did here was that every time I did not agree with an answer I consulted it with [Syllabus](http://www.istqb.org/downloads/viewcategory/16.html), [Glossary](http://www.istqb.org/downloads/viewcategory/20.html) or with colleagues during exam preparation training we had. We often did not agree with both unofficial and official (coming from ISTQB) sources but discussing and criticizing those sources taught me more than would learning the answers by heart.

Answer (score 2):

Some good practice paper you will find here on [istqbexamcertification](http://istqbexamcertification.com/).

Main thing is to concentrate on [syllabus given by ISTQB](http://www.istqb.org/downloads/finish/16/15.html).

As per my experience only some time questions come from practice paper in real exam. Paper is always based in ISTQB syllabus. So read , understand and remember each and every line of it.

Answer (score 2):

- [Quizzes](http://www.rogeriodasilva.com/istqb-free-quiz/) for all the exam topics.
- [Cheat Sheet](http://www.rogeriodasilva.com/software-testing-foundation-topic-cheat-sheet-istqb-iseb/) that covers all the topics.
- [Summary](http://www.rogeriodasilva.com/) of the whole syllabus.

NOTE : You will have to login to access the quizzes

Answer (score 1):

- I've found [this site](http://www.patshala.com/istqb/) to be pretty good.
- My favorite though is the [Skills NB site](http://skillsnb-competencesnb.skillport.com/).

You have to search for the course, but the tests are given in very well manner.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the kind of thing you are looking for, but [here's one place.](http://www.astqb.org/certified-tester/certification.php)

Answer (score 0):

The most comprehensive list of sites and materials from my perspective:

- http://testcompetence.com/
- https://www.toolsqa.com/software-testing/istqb-simulator-test-foundation-level-paper-1/
- https://astqb.org/resources/
- https://www.istqb.org/downloads/category/54-ctfl-2018-exam-files.html
- https://istqb.patshala.com/

Best books:

- [A Study Guide to the ISTQB® Foundation Level 2018 Syllabus: Test Techniques and Sample Mock Exams](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3319987399)
- [Software Testing: An ISTQB-BCS Certified Tester Foundation guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07VQJXYQR)