# Preparation for for the ISTQB Technical Test Analyst exam

Tags: istqb, certification

I use Syllabus 2019 and Glossary from the official ISTQB site. I found also some books, but those are quite old, like this one: Advanced Software Testing - Vol. 3, 2nd Edition: Guide to the ISTQB Advanced Certification as an Advanced Technical Test Analyst 2nd Edition, which was released in 2015.

I found also some question dumps, but don't know much about source and correctness. What kind of learning package or materials should I buy to prepare for this exam?

Comment: Please have a look here, there are some good links from users about ISTQB: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/5227/where-can-i-find-istqb-foundation-mock-exams-with-reliable-answers/5229#5229

Comment: https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=_fZnXwAACAAJ&hl=en  this is the best

Comment: Adam Roman's "A Study Guide to the ISTQB Foundation Level 2018 Syllabus"

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if this is appropriate or not - asking for specific materials about a specific exam seems like it would not be. In fact, Daniel's link looks like it should probably be closed. I should note that the comments here are not answers - they are comments recommending specific books - a real answer (which would be below these, not in the comments section) would have more than just a link or a name of a book. It would have strategies, explanations, personal experience, etc.